# Ayuda con documento Html y libreria dompdf

Tags: php, html, pdf

Necesito ayuda con documento que intento convertir de word a html y despues a pdf con dompdf no entiendo porque me hace un salto de casi 1 hoja y no queda continuo adjunto el codigo de la libreria aqui se ve  bien pero en el pdf da un salto de donde dice cedula hasta herramienta de casi 1 hoja

```html
<?php
require_once'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
// Reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// Instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
// Load HTML content
$dompdf->loadHtml(' <table style="border-collapse: collapse; margin-left: 4.8pt; margin-right: 4.8pt;" width="692">
<tbody>
<tr style="page-break-inside: avoid; height: 7.0pt;">
<td style="width: 519.25pt; border: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; height: 7.0pt;" colspan="2" width="692">
<p><strong>Nombre del Usuario: </strong>MAYERLY ANGULO CORDOBA</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 7.4pt;">
<td style="width: 259.65pt; border: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; height: 7.4pt;" width="346">
<p><strong>N&uacute;mero de Orden de Servicio:</strong> L070&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
</td>
<td style="width: 259.55pt; border: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; height: 7.4pt;" width="346">
<p><strong>Tel&eacute;fono:</strong> &nbsp;3232021532</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 7.4pt;">
<td style="width: 519.25pt; border: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; height: 7.4pt;" colspan="2" width="692">
<p><strong>No. De Cedula:</strong> 1010212772 de Bogot&aacute;</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 232.1pt;">
<td style="width: 519.25pt; border: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; height: 232.1pt;" colspan="2" width="692">
<p style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; line-height: normal;">&nbsp;</p>
<p style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; line-height: normal;"><strong>Herramientas</strong>: Se realiza entrega de computador port&aacute;til marca <strong>HP</strong> serie <strong>Pro desk 600 g1 sff</strong>, con n&uacute;mero de serial &nbsp;<strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;MXL4070KQW</strong>, con las siguientes caracter&iacute;sticas de hardware: procesador Intel core i5 6200u gen 6, memoria ram ddr 3 de 8 gb, disco duro de 500 gb de almacenamiento, pantalla antirreflejo de 21, color de equipo negro, con mouse de serial 674315-001 y teclado con serial 672646-163. se encuentra en un estado de <strong>usado</strong>.</p>
<p style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; line-height: normal;">&nbsp;</p>
<p style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; line-height: normal;"><strong>Servicios:</strong> precargado con los siguiente software&acute;s: Windows 7 profesional, office 2016 home &amp; business, winrar, vlc, Skype, adobe reader, adatec para pc, Firefox, Chrome, plugins de navegaci&oacute;n, configuraciones, impresoras locales de oficinas swisslub, correo corporativo en pc y dispositivo m&oacute;vil, redes wifi y LAN.</p>
<p style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; line-height: normal;">&nbsp;</p>
<p style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; line-height: normal;">Usted como usuario asume la completa y total responsabilidad en caso de da&ntilde;o, perdida y deterioro del equipo entregado, fuera del deterioro normal con buen uso del equipo. <span style="color: black;">Este</span><span style="color: black; letter-spacing: 0pt;"> equipo es una estaci&oacute;n de trabajo que SWISSLUB S.A.S. est&aacute; poniendo a su disposici&oacute;n para uso dentro de sus oficinas; en caso31 de requerir trasladarlo quedar&aacute; bajo su riesgo y responsabilidad; esto quiere decir que, si el equipo sufre alg&uacute;n da&ntilde;o o perdida, usted deber&aacute; pagar el reemplazo del equipo, inmediatamente. Por lo cual, con su firma, a que los eventos detallados anteriormente, el valor del equipo le sea, descontado de n&oacute;mina o en caso de retiro de su liquidaci&oacute;n definitiva. Asimismo, el costo de reparaci&oacute;n o cambio de elemento da&ntilde;ado o perdido, siempre y cuando este da&ntilde;o no provenga del desgaste natural del equipo.</span></p>
<p style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; line-height: normal;"><span style="color: black; letter-spacing: 0pt;">&nbsp;</span></p>
<p style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; line-height: normal;"><span style="color: black; letter-spacing: 0pt;">La estaci&oacute;n de trabajo, solo funcionar&aacute; y deber&aacute; funcionar exclusivamente en el desarrollo de las actividades inherentes a su cargo. La informaci&oacute;n que se genere en el desarrollo de sus actividades como funcionario de la compa&ntilde;&iacute;a, estar&aacute;n alojadas en el equipo c&oacute;mputo perteneciente a <strong>SWISSLUB S.A.S.</strong>, prohibi&eacute;ndose su copiado y/o distribuci&oacute;n de las mismas a otros medios de almacenamiento, comunicaci&oacute;n a personas y segregaci&oacute;n de esta informaci&oacute;n; acorde a lo estipulado en la cl&aacute;usula segunda numeral dieciocho de sus obligaciones contractuales suscritas en su contrato de trabajo y reglamento interno de trabajo, articulo 45 numeral 1. De ninguna manera el equipo ser&aacute; utilizado para trabajo personal, almacenamiento de informaci&oacute;n personal y/o desarrollo recreativo; esta rotundamente prohibido la instalaci&oacute;n de software adicional sin autorizaci&oacute;n del Departamento de las TIC &ldquo;tecnolog&iacute;as de la informaci&oacute;n y la comunicaci&oacute;n&rdquo;; acorde a lo estipulado en la cl&aacute;usula segunda numeral diecisiete de sus obligaciones contractuales suscritas en su contrato de trabajo y reglamento interno de trabajo, articulo 45 numeral 9.</span></p>
<p style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; line-height: normal;"><span style="color: black; letter-spacing: 0pt;">&nbsp;</span></p>
<p style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; line-height: normal;"><span style="color: black; letter-spacing: 0pt;">Adicionalmente est&aacute; prohibido subir o bajar de Internet, m&uacute;sica y otros archivos ajenos al trabajo. Si el equipo muestra da&ntilde;o o mal funcionamiento por causa de archivos mal intencionados, y se encuentra m&uacute;sica o archivos ajenos al trabajo de la compa&ntilde;&iacute;a, los costos por reparaci&oacute;n y mantenimiento reinstalaci&oacute;n del sistema operativo y de los dem&aacute;s programas estar&aacute;n a su cargo.</span></p>
<p style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; line-height: normal;"><span style="color: black; letter-spacing: 0pt;">&nbsp;</span></p>
<p style="text-align: justify;"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt;">Observaciones: </span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 6.2pt;">
<td style="width: 519.25pt; border: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; height: 6.2pt;" colspan="2" width="692">
<p style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; line-height: normal;">&nbsp;</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 6.2pt;">
<td style="width: 519.25pt; border: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; height: 6.2pt;" colspan="2" width="692">
<p style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; line-height: normal;">&nbsp;</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
   ');

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();

?>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que todos los parrafos estan ubicados dentro del mismo **td** y **dompdf** calcula si en el espacio restante de hoja esos parrafos se pueden renderizar completamente sino los añade en una nueva hoja, podrías hacerlo así:

```
<?php
require_once'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
// Reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// Instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
// Load HTML content
$dompdf->loadHtml(' <table style="border-collapse: collapse; margin-left: 4.8pt; margin-right: 4.8pt;" width="692">
<tbody>
<tr style="page-break-inside: avoid; height: 7.0pt;">
<td style="width: 519.25pt; border: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; height: 7.0pt;" colspan="2" width="692">
<p><strong>Nombre del Usuario: </strong>MAYERLY ANGULO CORDOBA</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 7.4pt;">
<td style="width: 259.65pt; border: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; height: 7.4pt;" width="346">
<p><strong>N&uacute;mero de Orden de Servicio:</strong> L070&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
</td>
<td style="width: 259.55pt; border: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; height: 7.4pt;" width="346">
<p><strong>Tel&eacute;fono:</strong> &nbsp;3232021532</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 6.4pt;">
<td style="width: 519.25pt; border: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; height: 6.4pt;" colspan="2" width="692">
<p><strong>No. De Cedula:</strong> 1010212772 de Bogot&aacute;</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<p style="margin-top: 20px; line-height: normal;"><strong>Herramientas</strong>: Se realiza entrega de computador port&aacute;til marca <strong>HP</strong> serie <strong>Pro desk 600 g1 sff</strong>, con n&uacute;mero de serial &nbsp;<strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;MXL4070KQW</strong>, con las siguientes caracter&iacute;sticas de hardware: procesador Intel core i5 6200u gen 6, memoria ram ddr 3 de 8 gb, disco duro de 500 gb de almacenamiento, pantalla antirreflejo de 21, color de equipo negro, con mouse de serial 674315-001 y teclado con serial 672646-163. se encuentra en un estado de <strong>usado</strong>.</p>

<p style="margin-top: 20px; line-height: normal;"><strong>Servicios:</strong> precargado con los siguiente software&acute;s: Windows 7 profesional, office 2016 home &amp; business, winrar, vlc, Skype, adobe reader, adatec para pc, Firefox, Chrome, plugins de navegaci&oacute;n, configuraciones, impresoras locales de oficinas swisslub, correo corporativo en pc y dispositivo m&oacute;vil, redes wifi y LAN.</p>

<p style="margin-top: 20px; line-height: normal;">Usted como usuario asume la completa y total responsabilidad en caso de da&ntilde;o, perdida y deterioro del equipo entregado, fuera del deterioro normal con buen uso del equipo. <span style="color: black;">Este</span><span style="color: black; letter-spacing: 0pt;"> equipo es una estaci&oacute;n de trabajo que SWISSLUB S.A.S. est&aacute; poniendo a su disposici&oacute;n para uso dentro de sus oficinas; en caso31 de requerir trasladarlo quedar&aacute; bajo su riesgo y responsabilidad; esto quiere decir que, si el equipo sufre alg&uacute;n da&ntilde;o o perdida, usted deber&aacute; pagar el reemplazo del equipo, inmediatamente. Por lo cual, con su firma, a que los eventos detallados anteriormente, el valor del equipo le sea, descontado de n&oacute;mina o en caso de retiro de su liquidaci&oacute;n definitiva. Asimismo, el costo de reparaci&oacute;n o cambio de elemento da&ntilde;ado o perdido, siempre y cuando este da&ntilde;o no provenga del desgaste natural del equipo.</span></p>

<p style="margin-top: 20px; line-height: normal;"><span style="color: black; letter-spacing: 0pt;">La estaci&oacute;n de trabajo, solo funcionar&aacute; y deber&aacute; funcionar exclusivamente en el desarrollo de las actividades inherentes a su cargo. La informaci&oacute;n que se genere en el desarrollo de sus actividades como funcionario de la compa&ntilde;&iacute;a, estar&aacute;n alojadas en el equipo c&oacute;mputo perteneciente a <strong>SWISSLUB S.A.S.</strong>, prohibi&eacute;ndose su copiado y/o distribuci&oacute;n de las mismas a otros medios de almacenamiento, comunicaci&oacute;n a personas y segregaci&oacute;n de esta informaci&oacute;n; acorde a lo estipulado en la cl&aacute;usula segunda numeral dieciocho de sus obligaciones contractuales suscritas en su contrato de trabajo y reglamento interno de trabajo, articulo 45 numeral 1. De ninguna manera el equipo ser&aacute; utilizado para trabajo personal, almacenamiento de informaci&oacute;n personal y/o desarrollo recreativo; esta rotundamente prohibido la instalaci&oacute;n de software adicional sin autorizaci&oacute;n del Departamento de las TIC &ldquo;tecnolog&iacute;as de la informaci&oacute;n y la comunicaci&oacute;n&rdquo;; acorde a lo estipulado en la cl&aacute;usula segunda numeral diecisiete de sus obligaciones contractuales suscritas en su contrato de trabajo y reglamento interno de trabajo, articulo 45 numeral 9.</span></p>

<p style="margin-top: 20px; line-height: normal;"><span style="color: black; letter-spacing: 0pt;">Adicionalmente est&aacute; prohibido subir o bajar de Internet, m&uacute;sica y otros archivos ajenos al trabajo. Si el equipo muestra da&ntilde;o o mal funcionamiento por causa de archivos mal intencionados, y se encuentra m&uacute;sica o archivos ajenos al trabajo de la compa&ntilde;&iacute;a, los costos por reparaci&oacute;n y mantenimiento reinstalaci&oacute;n del sistema operativo y de los dem&aacute;s programas estar&aacute;n a su cargo.</span></p>

<p style="margin-top: 20px; text-align: justify;"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt;">Observaciones: </span></p>

<table style="border-collapse: collapse; margin-left: 4.8pt; margin-right: 4.8pt;" width="692">
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 6.2pt;">
<td style="width: 519.25pt; border: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; height: 6.2pt;" colspan="2" width="692">
<p style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; line-height: normal;">&nbsp;</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 6.2pt;">
<td style="width: 519.25pt; border: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; height: 6.2pt;" colspan="2" width="692">
<p style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; line-height: normal;">&nbsp;</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
   ');

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();

?>
```

Ya de ahí en adelante le das el espacio entre parrafo y parrafo a tu gusto.

Answer (score 0):

El Contenido del `td` **Herramientas** no da en la hoja por que esta esta configurada horizontalmente .

Cambia:

```
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
```

Por:

```
$dompdf->set_paper("A4", "portrait");
```

O divide el contenido para que este acorde a la orientación de la de la hoja